# Display:inline-block elements, side by side stretch to parent?

Tags: html, css

I've got two inline-block elements, side by side, with a min-height set at 100%.  If I set an actual height on their parent wrap they stretch to it, but that's not what I want: I want them both to stretch to the size of the largest of the two.  Here's how they are structured:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="leftSection">
        <div style="height:200px;"></div>
    </div><div id="rightSection">
    <div style="height:300px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VT9Rk/

Easy with Javascript of course, but I'm looking for CSS only.  Thanks!

Comment: you might consider using a table.  That is the only way I know to have one div's size dependent on another, without the use of javascript.  If this is not helpful, perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, you've got me right.  I am trying to avoid the use of tables here and was hoping someone could offer an alternative.  I just don't understand, why doesn't the min-height do the trick?

Comment: I guess you also want those inner divs to adapt their heights to their content don't you?

Comment: will there be one of the divs that will alway be heigher than the other one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [css tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display).

Just add `display: table;` on your container div and

`display: table-cell;` on your leftSection and rightSection divs

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/VT9Rk/22/)**

### CSS

```
.container
{
    display: table;
}
#leftSection {
    display: table-cell;
    width:50px;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#rightSection {
        display: table-cell;
    width:100px;
    min-height:100%;
    background:red;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**PS:** Browser support is very good: IE8+, All modern browsers and mobile devices ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-table))

Answer (score 0):

How about using a flexbox:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">lorem</div>
  <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatem.</div>
</div>

.container {
    display:flex;
    width:300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container > div {
    width:50%;
}
.a {
    background-color: red;
}
.b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJzX2/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with flexbox:

set your holding container to `display: flex` and you should be set

http://jsfiddle.net/VT9Rk/